# aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent attribute on aws cli for AWS Identity Center users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

It seems that when using AWS Identity Center, mfa, and creating a aws cli session with `aws sso login` doesn't result in the cli session being mfa authenticated out of the box.

I have created an user, configured MFA, and configured aws cli using `aws configure sso` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-token.html). When I login using `aws sso login --<PROFILE NAME>` a browser windows opens to ask for password and mfa code, login finishes ok, and most aws cli operations with the profile work fine.

The problem is that operations which utilize policies that have the condition `"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": true` are not allowed. Is there some more configuration that needs to be done, or is it a feature of aws sso login that mfa status is not passed?

Answer (score 0):

aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent is not supported for identity center. Identity center does pass the mfa context to the session, reason why the operations are getting denied.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).